# php dom load wont load a variable?

Tags: php, xml, dom

My page that i had before worked fine til i tried to switch it to load the xml file from a variable. Now it just displays no info. What I am trying to do is make a drop box list with all the files found inside the "xml" folder and then be able to select one of those selections in the list box and scan that file and display its info.

XML File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<calibredb>
  <record>
    <id>5055</id>
    <uuid>83885ffc-93d8-41ba-aee2-e5c0ae48fc68</uuid>
    <publisher>Now Comics</publisher>
    <size>5803436</size>
    <title sort="Terminator - The Burning Earth 5, The">The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5</title>
    <authors sort="Unknown">
      <author>Unknown</author>
    </authors>
    <timestamp>2012-05-13T19:38:03-07:00</timestamp>
    <pubdate>2012-05-13T19:38:03-07:00</pubdate>
    <series index="5.0">The Terminator: The Burning Earth</series>
    <cover>M:/Comics/Unknown/The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5 (5055)/cover.jpg</cover>
    <formats>
      <format>M:/Comics/Unknown/The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5 (5055)/The Terminator - The Burning Earth 5 - Unknown.cbr</format>
    </formats>
  </record>
</clibredb>
```

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['xml']) && $_POST['xml'] != "") {
$loc = $_POST['xml'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->load($loc);  
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('record') as $e) {

$publisher = $e->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent; 
$title = $e->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;    

echo 'Title: '.$title.'<br/>';
echo 'Publisher: '.$publisher.'<br/>';

} 

}
```

And `$_POST['xml']` lets say = Now Comics.xml

Should I avoid using spaces in the file names?

Form Code:

```
<form name="xmlselect" method="post" action="convertxml.php">
<select name="xml">
<?php echo getXMLFiles(); ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My Complete Code For That Page:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("core.php");
function getXMLFiles() {
    if ($handle = opendir("E:/xampp/htdocs/sale/xml")) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry == "." || $entry == "..") {

            }else{
            $name = str_replace(".xml", "", $entry);
                echo '<option value="'.$entry.'">'.$name.'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['xml']) && $_POST['xml'] != "") {
$loc = $_POST['xml'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->load($loc);  
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('record') as $e) {

$publisher = $e->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent; 
$title = $e->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;    

echo 'Title: '.$title.'<br/>';
echo 'Publisher: '.$publisher.'<br/>';



} 

}
?>
```

Comment: You need to be careful with the line `$dom->load($loc);` where `$loc` just comes straight from the POST. Lots of configuration files these days are in XML.

Comment: not too sure what you mean, but this is a local only project. no one but me will be acessing this page. Can u not load it like that?!?

Answer (score 1):

The answer wast to cast the post to a variable first and i needed to include the exact location to the file.

```
$file = $_POST['xml'];
$loc = 'E:/xampp/htdocs/sale/xml/'.$file;
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->load($loc);
```

Comment: or a relative path like `'/xml/' . $_POST['xml']`